# Javascript: why does this function say that `...args` doesn't exist?

Tags: javascript

I have the following code:

```
let a = (b) => {
  console.log(...args)
  return function(...args) {

  }
}

let c = (d, e) => {

}

a(c)
```

When I comment out `console.log`, everything is fine. I assumed `...args` was the array of arguments to the function. But when I run `console.log` it says `ReferenceError: args is not defined`. Why is this?

Comment: You don't have any argument named `args` in your `a` function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

args should be like this. args are not defined

```
let a = (...args) => {
  console.log(args)
  return function(...args) {

  }
}

let c = (d, e) => {

}

a(c)
```

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things -

Console.log is trying to evaluate `args`, whereas when you return a function, you are not yet evaluating the parameters given to that function.

Args does not exist in the code you shared - it is not a built in like `arguments` is.   `Arguments` is the array you're looking for; args is commonly used as shorthand in function definitions because the word arguments is already taken.

Answer (score 1):

With arrow function you need change your parameter to ...args

```
let a = (...args) => {
  console.log(...args)
  return function(...args) {

  }
}

let c = (d, e) => {

}

a(c)
```

```js
let a = (...args) => {
  console.log(...args)
  return function(...args) {

  }
}

let c = (d, e) => {

}

a(c)
```

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript doesn't have a local variable args, it uses arguments